# file_get_contents(http://localhost:51089): no such host is known

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am following step-by-step guide of google app engine ["Using the User Service"](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/usingusers), but after I ran the app server locally

```
C:\Users\xxx>dev_appserver.py --php_exectuable_path="C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\php54\php-cgi.exe" C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\FirstPhpPrj\
```

below errors pop up:

```
Warning:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
 No such host is known.  in <b>C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\google_appengine\php\sdk\
google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy.php</b> on line 92

Warning:

    file_get_contents(http://localhost:51089)

: failed to open stream:
 php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  in C
:\Users\xxx\Desktop\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiP
roxy.php on line 92

Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'google\net\ProtocolBufferDecodeError' 
with message 'Not initialized: login_url' in C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\google_appengin
e\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\proto\ProtocolMessage.php:121

Stack trace:

    #0 C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\proto\
    ProtocolMessage.php(88): google\net\ProtocolMessage-&gt;mergeFromString('')


    #1 C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\Remote
    ApiProxy.php(109): google\net\ProtocolMessage-&gt;parseFromString('')


    #2 C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\ApiProxy.php(42): google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy-&gt;makeSyncCall('user', 'CreateLoginURL', Object(google\appengine\CreateLoginURLRequest), Object(google\app
    engine\CreateLoginURLResponse), NULL)


    #3 C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\api
    \users\UserService.php(69): google\appengine\runtime\ApiProxy::makeSyncCall('user', 'CreateLoginURL', Object(google\appengine\CreateLoginURLRequest), Object(google in C
    :\Users\xxx\Desktop\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\proto\ProtocolMessage.php on line 121
```

I browsed the log, there are two warnings and one fatal error. But not after I looked thru the coding of php sdk, i realized that this fatal error, caused by empty string input in "mergeFromString", is in fact caused by the warnings of"

```
file_get_contents(http://localhost:51089)
```

no such host is known", because in RemoteApiProxy.php, function CreateLoginURLResponse:

```
$serialized_remote_respone = file_get_contents(
'http://localhost:' . $this->apiPort, false, $context);
```

once serialized_remote_response gets an empty result, it will affect the command in next line:

```
$remote_response->parseFromString($serialized_remote_respone);
```

In this case, my own codes are actually irrelevant as it is exactly the same as the google sample codes:[here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/usingusers).

I just want to figure out why on earth, after google app engine starts its API server at

```
http://localhost:51089
```

yet it is not recognized! I tried pin this host and windows also threw error!

Comment: Having the same issue :( Didn't find any solutions yet